# Data won't be retrieved from mySQL by using JDBC in android studio

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve data from mySQL in android studio, However i cannot return any value, but some error pops up at the logcat. Here are my codes:

---

My table:
[image]

---

For Connection Class:

[image]

---

I used AsyncTask on MainActivity:

```
private class viewDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String z = "";
    boolean isSuccess = false;

    String about;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Please check your internet connection";
            } else {

                String query = "select * from medicines where name ='amoxicillin'";


                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    about = rs.getString("about");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            z = "Exceptions" + ex;
        }
        return z;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), about + z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     if (isSuccess) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

There's my code, quite messy. But the thing is I can't retrieve any data,

The error says "The url cannot be null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing `getConnection` twice in the Connection class? As you see, the second one has a `null` String as argument (`ConnURL`).

Remove that second attempt and it should do.

Also, please, don't add code to your questions as screenshots. Copy as text next time.

Comment: Great!  I used screenshot because when i tried to place my copied code as text, i was prompted to add more supporting details and I thought I have said everything in this question. And about that second `getConnection`, i thought I commented it earlier.